# Adding a button to the android emulator skin

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout

I'm trying to add a button to one of the default emulator skins. I used the layout file to get the button to appear but I'm not sure how to map it so that it actually does something.

Comment: Do you want to assign a click handler to your button?

Comment: Yes, but to a button on the skin

Comment: I want to change the actual emulator, in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to grab the button from the layout XML with something like this in onCreate:

```
Button xButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonX); //buttonX is the id you gave the button in the layout
```

Then you could set a click listener for that button in your onCreate like this:

```
xButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do stuff here    
}});
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The question is for a button on the emulator skin not layout xml.

Comment: Good question, I'm trying to think back 9 years ago but my answer isn't specific to the emulator so it doesn't seem to fit the question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Very late but here is what I've found:

1. Create your skin as normal with the button images in place (rendered)
2. Create a button overlay image which is going to be drawn over the button when you mouse move over it with the mouse (can be the same for all buttons given it is only meant to be a focus indicator)
3. In your skin define the button(s) in the layout (see below)
4. For each button you can link it to a specific qemu code (see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu.git/+/8b9887163ce94928aec159956d1a61fc93bb949d/android/skin/file.c#122)

layout:

```
parts {
  device {
     ...
  }
  portrait {
     ...
     buttons {
        search {                 // see qemu codes 
           image xxxx.png        // the overlay image to show on mouse move over
           x     00000           // the top-left coordinate to show the image
           y     00000           //
        }
     }
  }
}
```

PS: I am pretty sure the button size is dependant on the button image dimensions.